# Change Icon by Variable in a JButton

Tags: variables, icons, jbutton

I have a Variable PositionX and a Variable PositionY.
Now I want to set the Icon, to a specific Icon defined beforehand "x1y7".
So the Button Icon changes depending on the variables x/y.

I come from a (specialised) Version of C, and I want to program it like that:

button3.setIcon("x"+Positionx+"y"+Positiony)

so inside the () he computes the name of my Icon: x1y7.

How can I make that possible?

Thank you.